# Using Dataframe with several rows for each person, create another with a single row per person and get the mode of a certain attribute(per person)

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Pandas dataframe such as:

```
fName       lName       smokes  eye_color
Bob         McCain         1      black
Bob         McCain         0      black
Bob         McCain         1      black
Ryan        Diedre         0      brown
Ryan        Diedre         0      brown
Ryan        Diedre         1      brown
John        Madden         1      green
John        Madden         0      green
```

Constructed from the opinions of different family members about a person.

How do I create a dataframe such as:

```
fName       lName       smokes   eye_color
Bob         McCain         1       black
Ryan        Diedre         0       brown
John        Madden         1      green
```

In Python.

Basically, I want the second (new) dataframe to have a single row for every unique combination of fName and lName in dataframe 1. The "smokes" value should be the most repeated value for that person. If there is no repeated value, just pick the first. Smokes value can only be 0 or 1.

I might be dealing with dataframes containing thousands of rows, so an efficient answer is advisable. But any answer is sufficient for now.

EDIT: added scenario where mode isnt just one number to sample data

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: `If there is no repeated value, just pick the first.` - can you change sample data for this?

Comment: Do you also want the most repeated value for eye_color?

Comment: No, only "smokes" will have a different value. The other attributes are unchanging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) with first value, because it should return 2 values and need only one, for `eye_color` use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) if all values are same per groups:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['fName','lName'])
         .agg({'smokes': lambda x: x.mode().iat[0], 'eye_color':'first'})
         .reset_index())
```

If need most frequent values in both columns per groups:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['fName','lName'])
         .agg({'smokes': lambda x: x.mode().iat[0], 'eye_color':lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]})
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  fName   lName  smokes eye_color
0   Bob  McCain       1     black
1  Ryan  Diedre       0     brown
```

Comment: Why is `iat` needed here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby and then the [pd.Series.mode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html):

```
def filt(x):
    return x.iat[0] if len(x.mode())>1 else x.mode()

df.groupby(['fName', 'lName'], as_index=False).agg({'smokes': filt, 'eye_color': 'first'})

   fName    lName   smokes  eye_color
0   Bob     McCain   1       black
1   John    Madden   1       green
2   Ryan    Diedre   0       brown
```

the `pd.Series.mode` returns the most frequent value

Comment: mode should return 2 values so is necessary also filtering here by position

Comment: How to deal with the scenario where two values repeat the most? The code returns a list of numbers.

Comment: @MohamadMoustafa, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try `groupby`:

```
>>> df.groupby('fName', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.mode()).reset_index(level=1).iloc[:, 1:]
  fName   lName  smokes eye_color
0   Bob  McCain       1     black
1  Ryan  Diedre       0     brown
>>>
```